# Why does Rapunzel flip an atlas book with Eugene in the middle of the dance montage?

Tags: plot-explanation, tangled

When Rapunzel sees the town for the first time, she begins to dance and encourage random people to dance with her.

In the middle of this dance, we see her in a "library"? Flipping a book containing maps, before returning to the dance sequence again.

What is the significance of this scene?

Are we to understand that she became aware of how big is the real world?
Or maybe the map book was a random book to tell us that she acquired a lot of knowledge in the short period she was out on that day?

Does this scene have any effect in the remainder of the movie? Is it referenced later?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're exactly right. The sequence was a montage that showed Rapunzel realising the sheer wealth of entertainments that even a small town can offer; food she's never tried, painting a huge floor picture, group dancing and a trip to what must seem like a massive store of knowledge.

Don't forget also that her [own collection](https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/564x/f1/22/be/f122be45363dc0fe7457766fea21285a.jpg) consisted of just [three books](https://33.media.tumblr.com/01b494373e08c0828f5b832114eb6b37/tumblr_n1ctaxReu11tqs1heo1_500.gif), apparently hand-chosen by Mother Gothel. Someone as inquisitive as Rapunzel simply couldn't resist a trip to the bookshop. This story-board from the '[Art of Tangled](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0811875555)' book gives us a few extra panels showing the preceding events, with Rapunzel doing the classic movie *double-take* when she sees all of the books on display

[image]

You may wish to note that she's not just reading an Atlas, she's has open books about animals, architecture, science, horticulture and mythology.

[image]

This image from [Rapunzel: A Day to Remember](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1423141768) confirms that it was a bookshop
[image]